# printing a list that contained on Json file with python

Tags: python, json, geojson

I am new to python and i am working with some geojson files that contain a multiple objects each object represents a precinct. I need to print the coordinates for all of the precints how can i do this? i was trying this but it does not work:

```
import json
with open('districts and precinc data merged.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for i in json['features']:
  print(i['geometry']['coordinates'])
```

this is an example of the json file:

```
    {"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[552346.2856999999,380222.8998000007]]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":1,"STFID":"55001442500001","NAME":"0001"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[529754.7249999996,409135.9135999996],[529740.0305000003,408420.03810000047]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":2,"STFID":"55001537250001","NAME":"0001","COUSUBFP":"53725"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[508795.9363000002,441655.3672000002],[508813.49899999984,441181.034]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":6278,"STFID":"55141885750001","NAME":"0001","COUSUBFP":"88575"}}
]}
```

my desired output would be a for each line have the cordinates for each object like so:

```
[552346.2856999999,380222.8998000007]
[529754.7249999996,409135.9135999996],[529740.0305000003,408420.03810000047]
[508795.9363000002,441655.3672000002],[508813.49899999984,441181.034]
```

thank you for your help!

Comment: li deisred output would be something like a line for each object containing the districts. for example [552346.2856999999,380222.8998000007] in one line and [529754.7249999996,409135.9135999996],[529740.0305000003,408420.03810000047] on the next one and so on

Comment: It's better to edit the question to include that instead of a comment down here. You can format it better too.

Comment: sorry about that i have now edited the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your json. In first line you have 3 list open `[[[` but closing 4 `]]]]`. In your json file, replace `[[[552346.2856999999,380222.8998000007]]]]` with `[[[552346.2856999999,380222.8998000007]]]`.

Then you can use nested loop,

```
x =  {"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[552346.2856999999,380222.8998000007]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":1,"STFID":"55001442500001","NAME":"0001"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[529754.7249999996,409135.9135999996],[529740.0305000003,408420.03810000047]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":2,"STFID":"55001537250001","NAME":"0001","COUSUBFP":"53725"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[508795.9363000002,441655.3672000002],[508813.49899999984,441181.034]]]},"properties":{"OBJECTID":6278,"STFID":"55141885750001","NAME":"0001","COUSUBFP":"88575"}}
]}

for i in x["features"]:
    for j in i["geometry"]["coordinates"][0]:
        print(j, end=",") # replace `\n` with `,`
    print("\b") # removes trailing , 

# output,

[552346.2856999999, 380222.8998000007]
[529754.7249999996, 409135.9135999996],[529740.0305000003, 408420.03810000047]
[508795.9363000002, 441655.3672000002],[508813.49899999984, 441181.034]
```

Comment: it gives me the following error:  for i in json['features']:
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Comment: you have an error in your file, there is extra `]`. Please copy the json frm my code above and replace it in your file first